# Set selected item in select list - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have the following data structure in my firebase table:

[image]

Inside my `Angular2` application I retrieve the entries and and display them in a `select list` as shown here:

```
<select class="form-control" id="lookingFor" formControlName="gender" >
   <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
   <option *ngFor="let status of genderValue" [value]="status.id">{{ status.description}}</option>
</select>
```

As you can see my first item in the list is a please select, this is selected by default before they have saved their profile.  The issue I have is when they have saved their profile and reloaded the edit profile page the selected value is of course 'please select' when it should be either male or female.

After some searching I added the following attribute `[selected]` my code now looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="lookingFor" formControlName="gender" >
       <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
       <option *ngFor="let status of genderValue" [value]="status.id" [selected]="editProfileForm.controls.gender">{{ status.description}}</option>
    </select>
```

However when running the project, it selects `male` as default even if I delete the value from `Firebase` it'll always remain as male selected.

Regarding what I'm doing inside my ts file, I simply call `Firebase` build the select list, then call get User Profile, I then pass the profile values into my form setup (reactive).

So my question is, how can I have `Please Select` as selected if the user has not specified their gender, or if they have specified their gender then set the relevant item to selected.

NOTE: I use the uniqueId generated by firebase as the value that is saved when the user saves their profile.

This is the part where I configure my form:

```
// userProfile is returned from Firebase
// gender will either have a value or it'll be null.
this.editProfileForm = new FormGroup({
    seeking: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    gender: new FormControl(this.userProfile.gender, Validators.required)
 });
```

After the editProfileForm has been configured, it clear shows the value of gender:

[image]

Comment: When you delete the value from firebase make sure you updated the model with the new value.

Comment: @RomanC I've done that, I also closed the application all together and re-started it yet the issue outlined above in the question still persists

Comment: You should bind the property where you store selected value

Comment: I do bind the property, its bound to the user profile that comes back from firebase.

Comment: Do I need to ask you to post the code?

Comment: Added my form code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `editProfileForm.controls.gender` is always `true` (it is the form control instance itself), you have to check if the value of `editProfileForm.controls.gender.value` is the same as `status.id`

Comment: Can I do that on the `html` ?

Comment: I done the following in the `html` `editProfileForm.controls.gender == status.id` however when saving the profile after selecting `male` reloaded the page and selected item is `Please Select`

Comment: Are you sure that `this.userProfile.gender` and `editProfileFOrm.controls.gender` contain the right values, at the time the form is created?

Comment: I've logged `this.userProfile.gender` to the console and saw the Key for female.  I then inspected the select list an saw the same value for female as an option to select.

Comment: So at the time this line `gender: new FormControl(this.userProfile.gender, Validators.required)` get processed your value of  `this.userProfile.gender` is "female"

Comment: That's correct yes, It did just set the value to female, however when deleting the gender from Firebase and reloading the application nothing appears to be selected within the page, not even Please Select.  Inside my `gender: new FormControl(this.userProfile.gender, Validators.required)` if I remove userProfile.gender and set the value to `' '` then Please Select is selected.

Comment: I just added another photo showing the value of gender after the `editProfileForm` has been configured, this example I have selected male.  Yet when page loads It select `Please Select` you know I have a feeling it has something to do with `selected` on `Please Select` but I would of thought providing a gender value would've overrode that.

Comment: so it seems, if I use `editProfile.controls.gender.value == status.id` instead of `editProfile.controls.gender == status.id` within the `HTML` it sets the selected value.  Not 100% sure if that's the correct way to do because examples I have see they don't have the .value at the end...

Comment: Makes perfectly sense because `editProfile.controls.gender` is the formcontrol itself so you have to use `value` :P i updated my answer for future readers.

Comment: I have noticed something though, when I'v built my select lists and then set the initial selected value their seems to be a delay of 1.5 seconds before showing the selected value... if this normal? I thought `Angular2` was built for performance along with other things,

Answer (score 0):

The value in the `userProfile.gender` should be related to the option value, so it became selected.

```
<select class="form-control" id="lookingFor" formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]="userProfile.gender">
       <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
       <option *ngFor="let status of genderValue" [ngValue]="status.id">{{ status.description}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You souldn't use `ngModel` with model driven forms.