# Set the selected value of the drop down in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

`vatCodeList` is  an error  with string  codes.

Example:  `['34u' , '23' ,'tt']`

Need  to set the  selected  value there  .

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="vatCode">             
            <option *ngFor="let i of vatCodeList">{{i}}</option>          
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding select element to object in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `*.component.ts`

```
public vatCode: any;
```

Inside your `*.component.ts` you can set the value of `vatCode` to one of the values contained within `vatCodeList`, this will update the selected value.

Inside the `*.component.html`

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="vatCode" [(ngModel)]="vatCode">             
  <option *ngFor="let i of vatCodeList">{{i}}</option>          
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the value property like this

```
<option [value]="i" *ngFor="let i of vatCodeList">{{ i }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put an expression to the option tag to make an option `selected`

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="vatCode">             
            <option *ngFor="let i of vatCodeList" {{i == vatCode?'selected':'' }}>{{i}}</option>          
</select>
```

The variable should reference the value of the `InputControl`. Using reactive forms it would be easy to extract the value and put it into expression.

---

The easiest way to bind the element to the model with `ngModel` but you can check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614719/573032) solution helps.